# Reordering a sequence of objects in a normalised Redux data structure

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a normalised Redux data structure indexed by a string ID. Amongst other properties, each object in the state has a `sequenceNumber` which is used to display it in order in a list or grid. The items can be dragged and dropped to reorder them.

I'm struggling to find a neat, pure approach to updating the sequence numbers. What is a good way to do this in a Redux reducer?

---

My current `state` data structure is essentially:

```
{
    'asdf': { title: 'Item 1', sequence: 0, ... },
    '1234': { title: 'Item 2', sequence: 1, ... },
    'zzzz': { title: 'Item 3', sequence: 2, ... }
}
```

My action is

```
{ type: REORDER_ITEMS, oldRow: 1, newRow: 0 }
```

Which should result in the state

```
{
    'asdf': { title: 'Item 1', sequence: 1, ... },
    '1234': { title: 'Item 2', sequence: 0, ... },
    'zzzz': { title: 'Item 3', sequence: 2, ... }
}
```

My current reducer uses `Object.keys(state).reduce()` to loop through the items and modify the `sequence` one by one, depending on whether they are equal, greater or lesser than the desired row numbers. Is there a neater way to manage this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could normalize a step further : Extract the sequence in a separate state slice and store the order as an array of ids.

```
{
  items : {
    'asdf': { title: 'Item 1', ... },
    '1234': { title: 'Item 2', ... },
    'zzzz': { title: 'Item 3', ... }
  },
  sequence: ['1234', 'asdf', 'zzzz']
}
```

This way, you could have a separate reducer to handle actions modifying your sequence, only using array operations.

Comment: Yeah, the original example given is _not_ actually normalized fully.  Standard practice is to have a lookup table of items by IDs, and track ordering of items using arrays.  See the "Structuring Reducers" section in the Redux docs for more details on this topic: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html .

Comment: Oops, probably should have thought of that myself! Thanks